# What is 3" (750Pa) wg class?

Tags: hvac, ducts

According to [Sheet Metal & Air Conditioning
Contractors’ National Association (SMACNA)](https://www.smacna.org/) - leakage test  manual, It is not recommended that duct system constructed to 3" (750Pa) wg class or lower be tested. What is "*3" (750Pa) wg class*"?

Answer (score 3):

[Pa (Pascal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(unit)) is a unit of pressure (air or hydraulic pressure).  It's a very tiny unit, usually used in the thousands or millions.

"inch" in this context is "inches of water", another unit of pressure.  This one's easy.

Get a glass of water and a clear straw.  Suck on the straw just enough that the water comes up 3".  Or blow hard enough it goes down 3".  You guessed it - that is 3" of pressure (or vacuum).  AKA 750 Pascals.  You can do the same by plumbing a clear plastic hose into your duct and dipping it in a glass of water.

Since that's a pretty small amount of pressure, so I can guess this relates to the strength of a blower in a furnace's air handling system.

Just so you know... you've met ["inches of water"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch_of_water)... there's another one, ["inches of mercury"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch_of_mercury) often used by meterologists.  Same concept, but mercury is 14 times heavier than water.  Also "feet of seawater" for divers, and [lots lots more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_(unit)). Clearly, the standards committee was bored.

Comment: Specifically "*wg*" stands for "*water gauge*". So "*3" (750Pa) wg class*", is a class of duct designed for pressures up to 3 inches of water (750Pa).